Cypress Allure Report Created but allure-results Folder Not Generated
I'm trying to integrate Allure reports with Cypress in my project. The Allure report is being created, but the allure-results folder is not being generated. Below are the steps I've taken and the configuration I've set up.
Pre-requisites

Node.js (>= v18.16.0)
npm (>= 9.5.1)
Cypress (>= 13.x)
Cypress package version: 13.13.1
Cypress binary version: 13.13.1
Electron version: 27.3.10
Bundled Node version: 18.17.1
Typescript (>=v5.5.3)

cypress.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import allureWriter from "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer"

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    allureWriter(on, config);
    //require('@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer')(on, config);
      return config;
    },
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000",
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.ts",
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/index.ts',
    reporter: 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter',
    reporterOptions: {
      reportDir: 'cypress/reports',
      overwrite: false,
      html: false,
      json: true,
    },
    env: {
      allureReuseAfterSpec: true
    },
  },
});


cypress/support/index.ts
import '.'; 

import './commands';
import '@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin';

My test file sample, cypress/e2e/sample_test.cy.ts
describe('Sample Test', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
      expect(true).to.equal(true);
    });
  });

package.json
    "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin": "^2.40.2",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.29.0",
    "cypress": "^13.13.1",
    "cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^3.8.2"  
 },   "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"  
 }

Run Cypress tests using:
npx cypress run
or
npx cypress run  --env allure=true --spec cypress/e2e/test/sample_test.cy.ts  --browser electron --headed 
Issues:

The Allure report is created, but the allure-results folder is not generated.
There are no specific error messages indicating why the folder is not being created.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified Plugin Integration:
Ensured the Allure plugin is properly integrated into cypress.config.ts and imported in cypress/support/index.ts.
Re-checked Configuration Files:
Confirmed the setup is correct as shown above.
Manually Created Allure Results Directory:
I tried creating the allure-results folder manually, but it remains empty.

NOTE:

Once, I observed the allure-result folder created, and the files where in. XML format, for the next run.
I manually deleted the folder from my project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The @shelex/cypress-allure-plugin supports only Cypress versions before v12.14.0.
For newer versions of Cypress, please consider switching to the official Allure Cypress module: allure-cypress.
The documentation can be found on the Allure Report website: https://allurereport.org/docs/cypress/

Thanks, Dmitry,  Working fine by using @mmisty/cypress-allure-adapter plugin
I had to uninstall @shelex/cypress-allure-plugin
& install https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mmisty/cypress-allure-adapter, then able to generate a report which is compatible with latest cypress v13.

Your support file is named cypress/support/index.ts, but the default name is cypress/support/e2e.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}, see Testing Type-Specific Options - e2e.
If you update cypress.config.ts with this configuration,
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      require('@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer')(on, config);
      return config;
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/index.ts',

    ...
  },
})

it will now call import '@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin'.
Incorrect `cypress.config.ts` format
You have also used the incorrect format for configuration, it is the cypress.config.js format.
See Configuration File
That may also mean you need to use import allureWriter from "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer"; instead of require('@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer')

I have made the changes and executed them. same issue. The allure-results folder was not generated but the allure-report folder was created.
have edited the above post with the latest changes @ Natalie.Martinez
